# Eclipse Juno error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-juno

I have Juno installed for Android development, and after updating my Android SDK, I was prompted by Eclipse to also update ADT, which I did. However, after updating it, when I tried to run eclipse, I get the error message:

An error has occurred. See the log file filename.log

The log contains the following output.

[error output](http://pastebin.com/aQmxGwM2)

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already tried to reinstall latest version of eclipse and/or Android SDK?

Comment: are you running it linux.?